# Show non-convexity of a function with vector input

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

How does one go about proving non-convexity of the function d?

$$
d(v) = 1/2*||F(v)- p||^2
$$

$$
F(v)=\sum_{i=1}^n l_i*\begin{pmatrix}
cos(\sum_{j=1}^i v_j) \\
sin(\sum_{j=1}^i v_j
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
F: \Bbb R^n\rightarrow \Bbb R^2, [v,l] \in \Bbb R^n, p \in \Bbb R^2
$$

Proving it by use of the Hessian is not easy, so i figured it would be easier to use the definition of a convex function and a proof by contradiction but so far i've been unable to find a solution.

Comment: Is the norm Euclidean?

Comment: yes, that is the euclidean norm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $d$ is $2\pi$-periodic in every axial direction. The only way that such a periodic function can be convex is if is constant.